# How do I factorise this to easily find the roots?

Tags: polynomials

I have $f(x)=x^3-13x+12$. 
I know that this can be factorised to get roots of $f(x)=0$ to be $1,-4,3$. 
But what is the first step for this factorisation? How do I make the adjustments in similar problems?

Answer (score 3):

Since the coefficient of $x^3$ is 1, then the integer roots of $f(x)$ (if it exists) are divisors of constant term. In this case, the divisor of $12$. Let's try for $x=1$. Luckily, we get $f(1)=1^3-13\cdot1+12=0$. So, $x=1$ is a root of $f(x)$ and $x-1$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

Divide $f(x)$ by $x-1$ to get the other factor.

$$f(x)=(x-1)(x^2+x-12)$$

Since $x^2+x-12=(x+4)(x-3)$, then

$$f(x)=(x-1)(x+4)(x-3)$$

Answer (score 2):

For this specific problem there is a trick: decompose the middle term and do a partial factorization like this:

\begin{align}
x^3-13x+12=\\
x^3-12x-x+12 = \\
x(x^2-1) - 12(x-1) = \\
x(x-1)(x+1) - 12(x-1) = \\
(x-1)(x^2+x-12) = \\(x-1)(x+4)(x-3)
\end{align}

But this is a special case: in the general case you have to follow the Hagen's instructions.

Answer (score 1):

As the general formula for cubics is not taught, the fist step is to hope that at least one of the roots is rational. By the rational root theorem, such a root (of an integer polynomial with highest coefficient $1$) must be a divisor of the constant term, i.e., $\in\{\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4\pm6,\pm12\}$. After finitely many trials, you either find at least one such root or notice that this method is fruitless. Once you have one root, you can factor out its linear factor and are left with a quadratic. Or if you are lucky, as in this case, you keep finding all roots among the few candidates.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you will not be able to factorise polynomials easily. In fact, sometimes the cubics are difficult to do it. For example, try to factorise the following:

$$x^3-2x+8 = f(x)$$

It is almost impossible to do it, unless you know the cubic formula. In this example, the only real root is

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{-36 + 2 \sqrt{318}}{9}}+ \sqrt[3]{\frac{-36 - 2 \sqrt{318}}{9}}$$

However, you can use the Factor Theorem so as to get the rational roots. If they exist. If so, you must divide the equation by the following: $x-r$, which $r$ is the root that you have gotten (that also work when $r$ is not rational, but would not be a good idea doing it).

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to notice the relatively spot-able root of $x=1$, you can then factor out $x-1$ from the polynomial, and continue on with the resulting quadratic factor.